# Convert TimeSpan to float

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

How do I convert a TimeSpan to a float , taking into account all of the processing unit (hour minute) for example
if (unit = hour)
convert TimeSpan to a float hours

In another context, is there not a data type "Timespan" in SQL Server ?

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) the equivalent for `TimeSpan` is `time` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Total*` properties on `TimeSpan`, e.g. [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Example for minutes:

```
var t = new TimeSpan();
var total = t.TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
TimeSpan elapsedTime = new TimeSpan(125000);
float floatTimeSpan;
int seconds, milliseconds;
seconds = elapsedTime.Seconds;
milliseconds = elapsedTime.Milliseconds;
floatTimeSpan = (float)seconds + ((float)milliseconds / 1000);
Console.WriteLine("Time Span: {0}", floatTimeSpan);
```

The program output looks like this:

```
Time Span: 0.012
```

Answer (score 0):

```
internal static string TimeSpanToDouble(TimeSpan timeSpan, string unit)
    {
        double result = 0;
        if (unit.Equals("MINUTES"))
            result = timeSpan.TotalMinutes;
        else if (unit.Equals("HOURS"))
            result = timeSpan.TotalHours;
        else if (unit.Equals("DAYS"))
            result = timeSpan.TotalHours / 24;
        else
            throw new Exception();
        return Convert.ToString(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert.ToSingle`, like this:

```
var ts = new Timespan(0, 1, 1, 30);
var minutes = Convert.ToSingle(ts.TotalMinutes);
var hours = Convert.ToSingle(ts.TotalHours);
```

The resulting `minutes` and `hours` will be, respectively, `61.5` and `1.025`

Check out this dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uSQfk0

Answer (score 0):

```
double TsToHoursDouble(TimeSpan ts) => ts.TotalMinutes / 60;

double TsToMinsDouble(TimeSpan ts) => ts.TotalMinutes;
```

using:

```
var hrs = TsToHoursDouble(someTimeSpan);
```

if you need more accurate results, you can use TotalSeconds in such calculations